# What is this plant which looks like "marjoram"?

Tags: botany, species-identification

Place is **India**.

We are confused about the identity of this indoor plant. My friend is saying **plectranthus**, possibly **barbatus**.
I am saying it is **marjoram**.

Which is correct name for this plant?

[image]

Comment: It resembles very closely to Marjoram.

Comment: **This does not look like Marjoram!** Marjoram does not have denticulate leaves! *Plectranthus sp.* has, though. It does not  appear to be *P. barbatus* either since it has some kind of structures on the leaves that are not visible in your image. Could be another species of the genus ... Please do not consume unless you are sure what it is.

Comment: Apparently looks like *Coleus aromaticus*